# Associations between rails models and ActiveRecord queries

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, models

I'm trying to find all assets which were made by users who are older than the variable min_age. Currently, I'm trying to do it with this call:

```
assets = Asset.joins(:user).where("age(users.handles.first.birthday) >= ?", min_age)
```

Each asset has one user, and each user can have multiple handles.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :handles, :class_name => "UserHandle"

def get_current_age
    age(self.handles.first.birthday)
end
```

Here's the error I got:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in SearchController#data

Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.birthday) >= 90)' at line 1: SELECT `assets`.* FROM `assets` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `assets`.`user_id` WHERE (age(users.handles.first.birthday) >= 90)

Rails.root: /Users/Jimmy/Documents/Launchpad Toys/LPT_Repositories/orbit-analytics
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/search_controller.rb:254:in `find_by_user_current_age'
app/controllers/search_controller.rb:121:in `robot_search'
app/controllers/search_controller.rb:384:in `data'
```

Comment: Not a solution to your question: The reason for your error is you cannot put `"age(users.handles.first.birthday) >= ?"` in your `where()` as you have it. Strings in quotes like that are passed directly to MySQL; it's not evaluated by Ruby at all.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that that was causing this error. I'm not so much confused by what's causing the error as how to accomplish that without causing one. I tried defining that `get_current_age` method for users, but that results in a `Unknown column 'users.get_current_age'` error, although I have several other similar methods for the users model that all work. Any one have any ideas for how to get around this?